# javascript onkeypress input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning Javascript.. Below code working only if my script tag below my input text element, but if i place code above input text tag, its not working. May I know why? Below is code:

```
<head>    
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name" >   
    <script type="text/javascript">             
        var txtId = document.getElementById('name');    
        txtId.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
            console.log('Pressed!')
        })                      
    </script> 
</body>
```

Below code is same as above except that I am using function, inside which I am using same code as above. But in this case, my script tag is above input text tag, and its working. How it's working in this case?  Below is the code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">   
        function keyPressListener(){
            var txtId = document.getElementById('name');   
            txtId.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
                console.log('Pressed!')
            })
        }                   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="name" onkeypress="keyPressListener()">

</body>
```

So, what exactly difference  between above 2 codes?

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the `onkeypress` attribute. It actually works the same way as the `addEventListener`. You just have to write a simple function and call it in `onkeypress`

```
<input type="text" id="name" onkeypress="keyPressed()">

<script>
function keyPressed(){
    console.log('Key Pressed');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Why is not working to place above the input**
   -Because document was not ready .so you need `body.onload` event .see the body `onload=start()` it will apply the js function after body loaded

```html
<body onload="start()">
  <input type="text" id="name">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function start() {
      var txtId = document.getElementById('name');

      txtId.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
        console.log('Pressed!')
      })
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

***And the second one***  -you are using two function in a single event.     So use with any one of the event

> *if*    use with inline keypress of `keyPressListener()`   *else*   use Dom event of the 
>   keypress *`(addEventListener)`*

***Note:**

1. Dont include the `addEventListener()` inside `keyPressListener()` .
2. If you use with `addEventListener()` remove the `onkeypress` event inline of the markup.
3. because both are same action .

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function keyPressListener() {
      console.log('Pressed!')
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="name" onkeypress="keyPressListener()">

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `addEventListener`.

Or try this as your input:

Add a `;` after keyPressListener():

`<input type="text" id="name" onkeypress="keyPressListener();">`

If that doesn't work try this:

`<input type="text" id="name" onkeypress="keyPressListener(); return true;">`

HTML5 knows that when you use an `onkeypress` attribute that it needs to call the JavaScript function `when the key is pressed`. You can basically put any functional JavaScript in the parameter for the `onkeypress="`(JavaScript goes here)`"` attribute.

You can also just grab the element from the DOM and then add the event listener to the element like so:

jQuery: `$('#name').onkeypress( function() { //code goes here } );`

Regular Js: `document.getElementById('name').onkeypress( function() { //code goes here } );`

Comment: Why would you say that "addEventListener is deprecated"? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener certainly seems to disagree.